# Has there ever been a seaplane with retractable pontoons?

Tags: aircraft-design, seaplane

I would like to know if there's ever been a seaplane in which all of its pontoons or sponsoons are retractable after takeoff.

This could be a seaplane with 1 or 2 main pontoons that somehow retract. Or more likely, this could be a flying boat (bouyant hull) whose under-wing pontoons retract into the wing. I will also count a flying boat with only sponsoons that can retract somehow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There have been a couple of examples- the [Blackburn B-20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackburn_B-20), for example, had a retractable pontoon below the hull (and retractable wing floats), though it was an one-off experimental aircraft with a single flight to its credit.

[image: B20]

Blackburn B20, image from [dinger.byethost5.com](http://dinger.byethost5.com/blackburn_b20.htm?i=1)

As a more widespread example, the [Consolidated PBY Catalina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolidated_PBY_Catalina)'s wing floats were retracted electrically after takeoff.

[image: Catalina wing float]

Catalina's retractable wing float; image from [navy.memorieshop.com](http://navy.memorieshop.com/Sand-Point/PBY-Wing-Float.html)

Retractable floats have been used in other aircraft too- like the [Grumman G21A Goose](http://www.john2031.com/grumman/goose/photos_1.html) and the [SL-12C amphibian](http://www.seabee.info/spencer.htm). Some designs like the [Kawanishi E15K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kawanishi_E15K) featured retractable floats, which were later removed due to issues.

A little more digging reveals that the German [Ursinus Gotha WD 10 Fighter Seaplane](http://hud607.fire.prohosting.com/uncommon/aircraft/ursinus/index.html) had retractable floats quite early- during WWI!. However, I doubt it counts as the aircraft never went past taxiing stage.

[image: Ursinus]

Ursinus WD 10 fighter seaplane, image from [1000aircraftphotos.com](http://1000aircraftphotos.com/Contributions/Shumaker/12100.htm)